# Arc-node topology data structures in Python GIS packages

Tags: python, topology, fiona

I am looking at using the traditional arc-node topological data structure to make some spatial data analysis more efficient. I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel. Is there an implementation in any (preferably open-source) Python spatial data package where I could build and access the face, edge and node tables?

For background info, the topology is discussed for instance here http://library.oceanteacher.org/OTMediawiki/index.php/Vector_Data_Topology

Answer (score 2):

The traditional arc-node topological data structure presented here is the ESRI ArcInfo topology.
There are other topological data structures in the GIS World (GRASS vectors, PosGIS topology, SpatiaLite topology or the [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki) format). Look at  [Full planar topology in GRASS (Prima parte) (in Italian)](http://appuntigis.blogspot.be/2009/01/full-planar-topology-in-grass.html)   or [PostGIS topology ISO SQL/MM complete](http://strk.keybit.net/blog/2011/10/14/postgis-topology-iso-sqlmm-complete/) They all use the [Planar Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) theory.

There are no Python pure geospatial modules dealing with the ArcInfo topology (they are based on the [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) C++ library) but there are some to process the Grass vector, PostGIS or SpatiaLite topologies using GRASS GIS, PostGIS and SpatiaLite.

You could also emulate the Arc/Node topology in Python using modules as [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) ([PlanarGraph](https://github.com/paleroux/PlanarGraph) or using the [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki)/ [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) formats ([topojson.py](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/topojson.py) or [TopoJSON-Arcs](https://github.com/milkbread/TopoJSON-Arcs))

1) with GEOS (GeoJSON format: two adjacent polygons  from [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html))

[image]

```
import json 
with open("geos.geojson") as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)
print geojson
{u'crs': {u'type': u'name', u'properties': {u'name': u'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370'}}, u'type': u'FeatureCollection', u'features': [{u'geometry': {u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[245694.39030693972, 142516.89918805516], [246286.75570198838, 142258.93361279203], [246468.2870327291, 140778.02012517038], [245092.47063132576, 140510.50026934195], [245121.13347302168, 140988.21429760702], [244738.96225040962, 141523.25400926385], [245694.39030693972, 142516.89918805516]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'id': None}}, {u'geometry': {u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[246286.75570198838, 142258.93361279203], [247309.06372247558, 142707.98479936118], [247767.66918961002, 142526.45346862046], [248082.96044826496, 141523.25400926385], [247901.42911752424, 140806.6829668663], [246468.2870327291, 140778.02012517038], [246286.75570198838, 142258.93361279203]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'id': None}}]}
for geom in geojson['features']:
   print geom['geometry']
{u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[245694.39030693972, 142516.89918805516], [246286.75570198838, 142258.93361279203], [246468.2870327291, 140778.02012517038], [245092.47063132576, 140510.50026934195], [245121.13347302168, 140988.21429760702], [244738.96225040962, 141523.25400926385], [245694.39030693972, 142516.89918805516]]]}
{u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[246286.75570198838, 142258.93361279203], [247309.06372247558, 142707.98479936118], [247767.66918961002, 142526.45346862046], [248082.96044826496, 141523.25400926385], [247901.42911752424, 140806.6829668663], [246468.2870327291, 140778.02012517038], [246286.75570198838, 142258.93361279203]]]}
```

The result is two polygons with adjacent boundaries duplicated

2) with an arc-node topology from [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki)

```
from topojson.topojson import conversion
topo  = conversion.convert(geojson)
print topo['arcs']
[[[4628, 7955], [542, -6738]], [[5170, 1217], [-4113, -1217], [85, 2173], [-1142, 2435], [2856, 4521], [1772, -1174]], [[4628, 7955], [3056, 2044], [1372, -827], [943, -4564], [-543, -3261], [-4286, -130]]]
print topo['transform']
{'translate': [244738.96225040962, 140510.50026934195], 'scale': [0.33443326311184524, 0.21977043004492694]}
print topo['bbox']
[244738.96225040962, 140510.50026934195, 248082.96044826496, 142707.98479936118]
```

Here a single boundary can share several polygons

> For example, the shared boundary between California and Nevada is represented only once, rather than being duplicated for both states (from [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki))

Comment: Thank you very much. What I was after, however, is a way to build and access the individual Faces, Edges and Nodes tables. I do work with Fiona and Shapely ( and happily with GEOS), but I want to build, maintain and access the three distinct data structures ( tables, linked lists or whatever) that contain the symbolic links between the ids of faces, edges and nodes, rather than the coordinates themselves of a cleaned, topological structure. Thanks anyway for the answer.