# Python library to create topologies

Tags: python, topology, gml, topojson

Is there any Python library that facilitates the creation of topologies? I would like to create topologies using an open and portable format such as [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki) or [GML](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Geography_Markup_Language#GML_model).

The main goal is to save space in detailed polygonal topologies, with borders defined only once and shared among adjacent polygons.

The [Python GDAL/OGR](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/) library, for instance, does not seem to support topologies.

**Edit**: I am not interested at this stage on ESRI's ArcInfo topology, I rather work with [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki) or [GML](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Geography_Markup_Language#GML_model).  Also, in that thread that is supposedly a duplicate, there is this claim:

> There are no Python pure geospatial modules dealing with the ArcInfo
>   topology

Comment: Creation of topologies from where? From existing geographic data via inspection of polygon adjacency etc, or from scratch using a graph theory-style nodes/edge scheme (in which case see NetworkX)?

Comment: From nowhere in particular. It can either be from existing datasets or from geometries generated in the code itself. NetworkX is a library focused on graph theory and [does not seem to support](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/drawing.html?highlight=export) any geo-spatial formats.

Comment: look at [Arc-node topology data structures in Python GIS packages](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165684)

Comment: Gene, there are many links in that answer but none points to a library or API able to create portable topology files.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa NetworkX can be made to model existing spatial data. The easiest case is that it can read shapefiles: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.nx_shp.html

Comment: @Richard Law: Is the `networkx.DiGraph` class a spatial topology?

Comment: Define "spatial topology?" It's a directed graph. Whether that's an appropriate representation or not is up to you.

Comment: I recommend this article from the OSGeo Journal: [Spatial Relationships in GIS - Geospatial Topology Basics](https://journal.osgeo.org/index.php/journal/article/view/90).